# Set up a domain name to point to the host you're installing on

Tags: phabricator

I am installing phabricator following [this guide.](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/configuration_guide/) Step I am having hard time with is

> set up a domain name to point to the host you're installing on. You can either install Phabricator on a subdomain (like phabricator.example.com)

I am installing it in virtual box and I am not sure if I have to have a valid domain (bought?) or if I can set it up only locally which I need, I am supposed to only test the Phabricator functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only testing locally, you can set up a test domain name in your /etc/hosts file (C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts for Windows clients).  Usually you will use something like `phabricator.local` to avoid conflicting with real domains, but a subdomain that you or your organization owns is also an option.